# SQL where result = this but not this

Tags: sql

Results look like

```
A|1

A|2

B|1
```

Basically I want results to show only B in this scenario. I want results where I get B|1, but where A|1 does not show because A|2 also exists.

I dont want to just not show the A|2 result, which is what I'm doing with my current attempt.

Currently saying *where Column 2 is 1 and column 2 not 2*.

Comment: `Select * from tbl A where not exists (Select ID from tbl B where B.val <> 1 and a.ID = B.ID)`  basically define a set which would exclude b.  now say where not exists in that set  Assuming col1 = ID and col2 = val  this is but one approach but this may not handle what you really want.

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding your question. It may just be me but you should consider posting a sqlfiddle to more clearly demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Before you post something, please learn how to ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think you need to add a more complete description of what you want to see. Your presentation is not clear.  I initially thought you wanted B|1 and A|2, but *not* A|1 because it is "masked" by A|2.  But i"m not sure that's right.

Comment: There's no table structure, no table name, no column name, no sample input, no sample output.  How do you expect people to help?

Comment: There isn't any actual question(s) here, and if there is they're very hard to discern from your statements.  Please try again.

Comment: And if you had C 2 would you want C to show?  or if you had D 1, D2, and D3 would you ever want A1 and A2?  solution will vary based on desire/requirements

Comment: To get a good answer please show the your source structure and data

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `group by` and use `having` condition like

```
select col1,col2
from tbl
group by col1
having count(distinct col2) = 1
```

Comment: @xQbert, have no idea at all ... it's kind a guess answer based on posted data .. if OP edits and says something different will delete

Comment: I totally agree it's a viable answer given expected result; which is why I upvoted and asked.